# On the mathematics behind the Dyson Series

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, linear-transformations, quantum-mechanics

I've come across the Dyson Series solution of the Schrödinger Equation arising in the interaction picture when dealing with a time dependent Hamiltonian. Since then I've been looking for a rigorous definition of the integral of operators which appears repeatedly in the formula but I didn't find much. Is there perhaps a general theory of this type of integrals? Or is it just a formal definition whose meaning I've not understood? Anyhow I'd appreciate very much if you could suggest any reference about the topic.
Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: You might look at Reed and Simon, [Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics II: Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/II_Fourier_Analysis_Self_Adjointness/14XvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en), sec. X.12: Time-dependent Hamiltonians.